# android.media.AudioManager.setStreamVolume(int streamType, int index, int flags)

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I am trying to change volume of notifications, but not ringer.
However, when I use this function notification and ringer volume are changed.

Example code:

```
AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
int volNot = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
int volRing = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(STREAM_RING);
Log.d(volNot + "," + volRing, "not, ringer");
mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 1,  0);
volNot = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
volRing = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(STREAM_RING);
Log.d(volNot + "," + volRing, "not, ringer");
```

For result `setStreamVolume(STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 1,  0)` changes value of `notifications(STREAM_NOTIFICATION)` to 1, but it also changes value of `ringer(STREAM_RING)` to 1.

Answer (score 4):

This is because the phone has a setting in sounds---> volume in which there is a tick box which is checked, uncheck it and try your code again, this setting says that the ringer volume will be your notification volume and visa-verse.

Answer (score 0):

Since ICS (Android 4.0), Ringer and Notification shares volume stream in official Android ROMS. Before this, user could choose to split the streams.